# Factory is undefined in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack

I am following a tutorial and trying to set up Angular.

I keep getting this error in my code...

> Error: [$injector:undef]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.0/$injector/undef?p0=Bear

Here is the order of files in the `<head>` tag in the html

```
<script src="js/services/BearService.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/BearCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

Here is my BearService.js file...

```
angular.module('BearService', []).factory('Bear', ['$http', function($http) {
  // some code (is this relevent?)
}]);
```

and my BearCtrl.js file...

```
angular.module('BearCtrl', []).controller('BearController', ['$scope','Bear', function($scope, Bear) {

}]);
```

and my app.js file...

```
angular.module('sampleApp', ['ngRoute', 'appRoutes', 'MainCtrl','BearService', 'BearCtrl']);
```

EDIT: I tried changing the orders of when the files are called in my HTML file but it didnt make a difference.

Comment: the *full* link for that error, https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/undef?p0=Bear reveals that the issue is that your factory isn't returning a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out. It was due to my lack of knowledge as to how the setup works.

Where I wrote...

```
// some code (is this relevent?)
```

It turns out this WAS relevent. Changing this to `return 'test';` solved that problem.